# What does the quoted section in someone’s name mean?

Tags: names, quotations, quotation-marks

As in the title, what does a quoted section in a name mean? Names like John “James” Doe (not someone’s name)

Comment: What does your research show?

Comment: When presented like that the quoted part is the nickname or "known-as" name of the individual.

Comment: My research shows info about quotation usage in writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually refers to a nickname, or something that other people might call that person that isn't their given name.  So in the example you gave, that person's formal given name is John, but most people probably call him James.